# In a jqxGrid, how would I differentiate between a row that has data and a row of length 0?

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid

I have a grid that contains n number of rows. This grid contains a column that is a checkbox and this checkbox allows the end user to either add the row or not to the database. My issue is my code is adding everything. Viable data and empty rows. How can I tell if the row is literally of 0 length?

**Code for the Grid**

```
    var data = {};

    var source = {
      localdata: data,
      datatype: "array",
      datafields: [{
        name: 'UOMRelatedUnit_ID',
        type: 'string'
      }, {
        name: 'UOMRelatedUnit_AddItem',
        type: 'bool'
      }, {
        name: 'UOMRelatedUnit_Name',
        type: 'string'
      }, {
        name: 'UOMRelatedUnit_Abbreviation',
        type: 'string'
      }, {
        name: 'UOMRelatedUnit_ConversionOfBaseUnits',
        type: 'number'
      }],
      addrow: function(rowid, rowdata, position, commit) {
        //Server Action
        commit(T);
      },
      updaterow: function(rowid, newdata, commit) {
        //Server Action
        commit(T);
      }
    };
    var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

    $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").jqxGrid({
      width: 500,
      height: 200,
      source: dataAdapter,
      editable: T,
      selectionmode: 'singlecell',
      theme: 'energyblue',
      showtoolbar: T,
      rendertoolbar: function(toolbar) {
        var me = this;
        var container = $("<div style='margin: 5px;'></div>");
        toolbar.append(container);
        container.append('<input id="addUoMRelatedUnitsRowButton" type="button" value="Add New Row" />');
        container.append('<input style="margin-left: 5px;" id="addUoMRelatedUnitsMultipleRowsButton" type="button" value="Add Multiple New Rows" />');
        $("#addUoMRelatedUnitsRowButton").jqxButton();
        $("#addUoMRelatedUnitsMultipleRowsButton").jqxButton();

        // create new row.
        $("#addUoMRelatedUnitsRowButton").on('click', function() {
          $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").jqxGrid('beginupdate');
          var GridObject = ['']
          var commit = $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").jqxGrid('addrow', null, GridObject);
          $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").jqxGrid('endupdate');
        });

        // create new rows.
        $("#addUoMRelatedUnitsMultipleRowsButton").on('click', function() {
          $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").jqxGrid('beginupdate');
          for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var GridObject = ['']
            var commit = $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").jqxGrid('addrow', null, GridObject);
          }
          $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").jqxGrid('endupdate');
        });
      },
      columns: [{
        text: '',
        editable: F,
        datafield: 'UOMRelatedUnit_ID',
        width: 0
      }, {
        text: 'Add',
        editable: T,
        datafield: 'UOMRelatedUnit_AddItem',
        columntype: 'checkbox',
        width: 40
      }, {
        text: 'Name',
        editable: T,
        datafield: 'UOMRelatedUnit_Name',
        columntype: 'textbox',
        width: 200
      }, {
        text: 'Abbreviation',
        editable: T,
        datafield: 'UOMRelatedUnit_Abbreviation',
        columntype: 'textbox',
        width: 100
      }, {
        text: '# of Base Unit',
        editable: T,
        datafield: 'UOMRelatedUnit_ConversionOfBaseUnits',
        columntype: 'textbox',
        width: 100
      }]
    });

     // select or unselect rows when the checkbox is checked or unchecked.
    $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").bind('cellendedit', function(event) {
      if (event.args.value) {
        $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").jqxGrid('selectrow', event.args.rowindex);
      } else {
        $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").jqxGrid('unselectrow', event.args.rowindex);
      }
    });

    $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").jqxGrid('beginupdate');
    var GridObject = ['']
    var commit = $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").jqxGrid('addrow', null, GridObject);
    $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").jqxGrid('endupdate');
```

**Current Code for determining an empty row**

```
if(!row.UOMRelatedUnit_AddItem || row.length === 0) {
    _row["Name"] = $("#txtUnitOfMeasureSetName").val();
    _row["Active"] = T;
    _row["UnitOfMeasureTypeID"] = $("input[type='radio'][id='rblUnitOfMeasureType']:checked").val();
    _row["BaseUnitID"] = $("input[type='radio'][id='rblUnitOfMeasureBaseUnit']:checked").val();
    _row["RelatedUnitDisplayOrder"] = RecordCount;
    _row["RelatedUnitName"] = row.UOMRelatedUnit_Name;
    _row["RelatedUnitAbbreviation"] = row.UOMRelatedUnit_Abbreviation;
    _row["RelatedUnitConversionRatio"] = row.UOMRelatedUnit_ConversionOfBaseUnits;
    _row["UnitOfMeasureSetID"] = UnitOfMeasureSetID;
    _UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitData[index++] = _row;
    RecordCount += 1;
}
```

**EDIT 1**

Example of Empty Rows in grid.

[image: Empty Rows]

Comment: When would a row (array) of length 0 have data? Or why would a row with data (even 0/default data) have a length of 0?

Comment: @user2864740, when a user has added too many empty rows as seen in the image above.

Comment: You mean probably jqxGrid instead of jqGrid? You should change the tag of the question and replace the name in the text.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer, all I need to do is check to see if the AddItem column is undefined and that did the trick:

`if($.type(row.UOMRelatedUnit_AddItem) !== "undefined")`